# Can't get JSON response with swift

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have such swift code where in the storyboard is E-mail,Username,Password text fields and Register button:

http://pastebin.com/jBkbxDCh

And the userRegister.php is stored at /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/test , which code is:

http://pastebin.com/n36DJTTg

I have database named test and there is table named users with additional information.

So when i start app and enter all the fields and push register button, it doesnt do anything. And it doesnt even store new user in database. And when i try localhost/userRegister.php in browser it doesnt show anything there.

Can somebody help me with this huge problem of mine? Thank you!

Comment: Could you perhaps include the code in your post? It is long, so maybe you could try to get a minimal example where the bug happens.

Comment: well, i dont know php almost at all so i think that the main problem is that xcode doesnt get any response from .php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `$_GET`

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

And then use the url : `localhost/userRegister.php?email=name@example.com&password=password`

**Test**

```
<?php
require(“Conn.php”);
require(“MySQLDao.php”);

    $dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password);
var_dumb($result );
?>
```

See if you get any result by testing, something like this

Comment: Does not show anything.

Comment: are you shure you 'MySQLDao' class works?